# VisualForce Page Set URL Parameter w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a custom search VisualForce page. I have an inputText area for a search term, upon hitting enter I wan't to pass that value to URL parameter. Trying to do it via JavaScript.

I want URL to be apex/pageName?s=ValueEnteredInSearchBox

This is what I have right now which isn't working.

```
<body id="bodyPortalCaseSearch">
    <apex:form id="frmPortalCaseSearch">
        <apex:pageBlock id="pbPortalCaseSearch">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="tableRow">
                    <div id="searchDiv" class="tableCell">
                        <apex:inputText id="searchinput" style="width:85%; height:25px;margin:0; padding: 0px 6px 0px;"
                        title="Portal_Search_Phrase" value="{!portalSearchModel.searchTerm}" onkeypress="insertSearchParam()"
                        />
                        <apex:commandLink id="goSearch" title="Search" style="text-decoration:none;"
                        rerender="asQuestions,asAnswers,asSolutions,asIdeas,asCases,asContent">Search</apex:commandLink>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function insertSearchParam() {
                                var val = document.getElementById("{!$Component.searchinput}").value;
                                document.location.search = "?s=" + val;
                                searches();
                            }
                            document.getElementById("{!$Component.searchinput}").onkeypress = function (e) {
                                if (!e) e = window.event; // resolve event instance
                                if (e.keyCode == '13') {
                                    insertSearchParam();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        </script>
```

Comment: Why do you not use with action in apex:commandLink and with portalSearchModel.searchTerm in controler?

Comment: This is a javascript question. Removed salesforce to get more attention.

Comment: Please describe how it is not working. Can you put in some console.log() to check if your code is getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!addParameter}" id="goSearch" title="Search" style="text-decoration:none;"rerender="asQuestions,asAnswers,asSolutions,asIdeas,asCases,asContent">Search</apex:commandLink>



 public Pagereference addParameter(){
            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('s',portalSearchModel.searchTerm);
            return null;
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am getting this error message when I click on the commandLink... "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal view ID addParameter. The ID must begin with / "

Comment: Now I am getting this error:  "Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!addParameter}' in component <apex:page> in page portalcasesearch"